# Eclipse refactor pathways

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, refactoring

Imagine a pathway

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/texture/img.jpg"));
```

when renaming my picture img.jpg the pathway wont be updated. Is there anyway to automate this? Plugins?

thanks!

Comment: To be explicit, are you renaming the resource in Eclipse, via *Refactor>Rename*?

Comment: yes I am renaming them in the correct way. But there is obviously not a connection between the input string and the resource, that's whats bugging me...

Comment: I suspect the answer is no, particularly for relative paths. The IDE does not know what the current working directory will be at runtime. How would it know that that particular string is associated with the resource file you're renaming?

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of "/ How do you tackle the problem of renaming a resource? Do you manually edit all paths? Seems like a lot of work!

Comment: If renaming a single resource, you should have to change just the single definition of its path in the code. The DRY principle helps here. Are you finding it necessary to rename many resources?

Comment: Not for right now but maybe further down the line! Thx